# How can I use a 'keydown' event listener on a div?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keydown

I am trying to capture keydown events where specific keys correspond to specific audio clips to be played. I've been searching but I am stumped. It seems that the keydown event is only available in the window/document object. Is this correct? Ive seen some talk of jQuery plugins, although i would like to stay away from jQuery. Vanilla JS is ideal.

I have 2 DIVS that I want to listen for keydown events on at the same time. Based on which keys are pressed, the function plays the corresponding audio clip.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Consider doing some more research and refining your question to address a *specific* issue, as it's currently a bit too broad. Per [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: As you might have valid reasons to stay away from jQuery. I still would like to say that jQuery is a great addition to traditional java script. It has a lot of advantages that you can't do better yourself with traditional java script. (Sorry got triggered by "Vanilla JS is ideal")

Comment: gotcha. no problem, I only say that cause I am focused on learning javascript in itself. i dont want to fall into the allure of jquery is easier so just do it that way. I want to understand the process on a fundamental level.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Give the `div` a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex), so it will be focusable. In your case, a tabindex of -1 would be best as it would allow the element to be focused but remain inaccessible by the tab key.

> The tabindex global attribute indicates if its element can be focused, and if/where it participates in sequential keyboard navigation (usually with the Tab key, hence the name).
>
> A negative value (usually tabindex="-1") means that the element should be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation. It's mostly useful to create accessible widgets with JavaScript.

You can then add a keydown event listener to the element and check for the keyCode of the event.

```
document.getElementById("someId").addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    //do something on keydown
    if(event.keyCode==13){
     //enter key was pressed
    }
    if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90){
       //input was a-z
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked very well for me so far. Thank you! It makes sense to use conditionals to specify significance of the keys. that way I only have to use the keydown on the window object.

Comment: @TechtronixWeb I'm happy to have been of help!

Answer (score 10):

You can allow an element to receive focus by giving it a tab index.

```
<div tabindex="-1"></div>
```

As long as it's in focus key events should be captured on it.

If you want the element to be focusable using the Tab key, give it an index greater than -1.

[Simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/3wudb8p7/4/)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So can you only have one keydown event active at a time because the event element needs to be in focus?

Comment: Unless an event is cancelled, parent elements will still be notified. This means you can also capture the event within `document.body` or `window`. You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture