# Why (keydown.enter) and (keydown) dont work for list?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have list of elements:

```
<div class="List">
<div class=" SearchListItem" [ngClass]="{ active: i == activeIndexResultItem }"
          *ngFor="let item of searchShortResultItems; let i = index"
          (mouseenter)="mouseEnterItem($event, i)" (keydown.enter)="searchByEnter($event, item)"
          (click)="selectSearchResult(item)"> {{ item.text }} 
        </div>
</div>
```

Why `(keydown.enter)` does not work?

```
searchByEnter(e, item) {
   console.log(e); // no invoke
}
```

Also I have tried to change to:

```
(keydown)="searchByEnter($event, item)"
```

The same result

Also I havea set focus on: `<div`class="List"`#searchList>`:

```
 if (this.searchList) {
      setTimeout(() => this.searchList.nativeElement.focus(), 50);
}
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267273/how-can-i-use-a-keydown-event-listener-on-a-div

Comment: So how is the div going to get focus in order to fire key events?

Comment: Where I shouls set focus on list items or on list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard events are only dispatched on focused elements. You can add `tabindex="0"` to make your DIV focusable.

If your parent element is focused and you just keep track of current element from the list — add (keydown.enter) to parent element and pass your active item to that handler.

Comment: Add to list element?

Comment: add to `div class="SearchListItem"`

Comment: it is dinamically item, I can not add -1 for all iems in loop

Comment: You need to add 0 for all items, that means they are focusable in their natural order

Comment: Also I need to st focus for parent list?

Comment: Should I focus parent? <div class="List">? Because now I can not move by keys up/down in list

Comment: If you want to be able to move with arrows, not with tab / shift+tab you need to implement it on your own with keydown.arrowUp and keydow.arrowDown with proper handlers

Comment: I have implemented, by it requires focus on parent list. But now fucus is on element of list. Thats is why list is not scrolling by keys

Comment: Then, if your parent element it focused ignore my commens. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Okay I will try to add keyentr for parent

Comment: it does not work becasu by enter  I need to pass elemenet of list

Comment: Focus is lost from parent when I hover, focus on element, that i why keyenter does not work for parent, for items too

Comment: item from the list is `searchShortResultItems[activeIndexResultItem]`