# How do I listen to the keyboard using Fable in an Elmish app?

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

Using Fable in an Elmish app, I'd like to listen to the keyboard directly and get each keystroke as a message.

The Elmish documentation has a page on [Subscriptions](https://elmish.github.io/elmish/docs/subscription.html), which shows how to convert JavaScript events to messages. In my case, the events are "keydown" events, and I found [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4416533/1383366) in JavaScript to capture "keydown" events.

However, I'm having trouble putting the F# code together. My issue is that I don't know how to access the `keyCode` from the event raised when a key is pressed. Here's the code I have so far:

```
let keyDown initial =
    let sub dispatch =
        document.addEventListener("keydown", fun e ->
            dispatch (KeyDown e.keyCode))  // keyCode is not accessible here
    Cmd.ofSub sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `onKeyDown` instead of adding an event listener. If you generate your HTML elements using [Feliz](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Feliz), you can dispatch on keydown like this:

```ml
Html.input [
    prop.onKeyDown (fun evt ->
        dispatch (KeyDown evt.key))
]
```

Alternatively, you can probably use [dynamic typing](https://fable.io/docs/communicate/js-from-fable.html#what-is-dynamic-typing) to access the property by name (bypassing the type checker):

```ml
open Fable.Core.JsInterop

document.addEventListener("keydown", fun e ->
    dispatch (KeyDown e?keyCode))   // use ? operator
```

I haven't tried that, though, and wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I'm using Feliz, but the `prop.onKeyDown` doesn't seem to work on `Html.div`. It does work on `Html.input`, but I don't want to show a text box.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the second method, where I put your code above as the first thing in my `render` function.

Comment: Actually, putting it in `render` caused the app to behave strangely, so finally I used the "Subscription" method and it works well. Another change I made was to use the `key` property (which gives me the key as a `string`) rather than `keyCode` (which gives me the ASCII number).

Comment: According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51267699/344223), you need to give the `div` a `tabindex` value in order for `onKeyDown` to work.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you know that the event produced by a keydown is actually a Browser.Types.KeyboardEvent and not only Browser.Types.Event
So you can safely downcast

```
let keydown (event: Event) =
    let keyboardEvent = event :?> KeyboardEvent
    printfn "%A" keyboardEvent.key

document.addEventListener("keydown", keydown)
```